# Is there a site ranking HTML (Top 20%)

Tags: html, list, ranking

I am searching for a site that ranks the top 20% of everything HTML. This can be any ranking system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Funny you should ask.
I'm working on something on [my own site](http://phillipsenn.com/Tech/Tech.cfm?TurnID=100).